# Correct class loading PHP

Tags: php, autoload

I'm learning OOP in PHP and I faced the problem of correct classes loading. I have a registration form in the HTML file, the data from which are processed by PHP scripts. I have one parent class and several children classes, each in different files. I want to load each of child classes automatically into the parent.

Here is my parent class in which I initialize the child object.

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) { /*load the child class*/
    include $class . '.php';
});

$addTxt = new AddTxt(); /*init child class object*/

class Validator {
    public $name  = 'name ';
    public $s_name  = 's_name ';
    public $email = 'email ';
    public $ticket = 'ticket ';
    function __construct(){
        $this->name = $_POST['name'];
        $this->s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
        $this->email = $_POST['email'];
        $this->ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
    }
}

$validate = new Validator();
```

Here is a child class

```
<?php

class AddTxt extends Validator {
    public $string = "test";
    public $file;
    public $date;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->date = date('d_m_Y');
        $this->file = 'registration_' . $this->date . ".txt";
        $this->string = $this->name . " " . $this->s_name . " " . $this->email . " " . $this->ticket . PHP_EOL;
    }
    function addLine(){
        if(file_exists($this->file)){
            $f = fopen($this->file, "a+") or die ("Error");

            if (($f) && filesize($this->file)) {
                $lines = explode("\n", fread($f, filesize($this->file)));

                foreach($lines as $line){
                    $l = explode(" ", $line);
                    $line_items[] = $l[2];
                }
                foreach ($line_items as $item) {
                    if($item === $this->email) {
                        die ("such email already exist");
                    }
                }
                fwrite($f, $this->string);
            }
            else {
                fwrite($f, $this->string);
            }

            fclose($f);
        }
        if(!file_exists($this->file)) {
            $f = fopen($this->file, "a+") or die ("Error");

            fwrite($f, $this->string);

            fclose($f);
        }
    }
}


$addTxt = new AddTxt();/*another one child class init*/
$addTxt->addLine()
```

As you can see, the object of the child class is initialized twice, otherwise, I get this error `Call to a member function addLine () on a non-object`, like I did not create an object. It seems to me that this is the wrong way. I want to initialize the object only once. 
Tell me how to properly connect classes?
Is there any better way to load and init classes?

Comment: Would avoid reinventing the wheel on this one. Not something I say often. Feel like there is a standard now though... https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ code eg. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md

Comment: Can't you use composer's autoloader like ant other sensible person: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: You store classes in separate files, nothing else belongs into those files, so no object initializations. Those belong to the calling scope, where you load the classes.

Comment: Related: [PSR-1: Basic Coding Standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/): *Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.)
or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.)
but SHOULD NOT do both.*

Comment: Consider using fputcsv or serializing your entries.  Exploding entries on a space, your delimeter at the moment, is brittle as there is no filtering on your entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be initializing the class in the same file of your class. Move your classes into their own files.

#### Validator.php

```
<?php

class Validator {
    public $name  = 'name ';
    public $s_name  = 's_name ';
    public $email = 'email ';
    public $ticket = 'ticket ';

    function __construct(){
        $this->name = $_POST['name'];
        $this->s_name = $_POST['s_name'];
        $this->email = $_POST['email'];
        $this->ticket = $_POST['ticket'];
    }
}
```

#### AddTxt.php

```
<?php

class AddTxt extends Validator {
    public $string = "test";
    public $file;
    public $date;
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->date = date('d_m_Y');
        $this->file = 'registration_' . $this->date . ".txt";
        $this->string = $this->name . " " . $this->s_name . " " . $this->email . " " . $this->ticket . PHP_EOL;
    }
    function addLine(){
        if(file_exists($this->file)){
            $f = fopen($this->file, "a+") or die ("Error");

            if (($f) && filesize($this->file)) {
                $lines = explode("\n", fread($f, filesize($this->file)));

                foreach($lines as $line){
                    $l = explode(" ", $line);
                    $line_items[] = $l[2];
                }
                foreach ($line_items as $item) {
                    if($item === $this->email) {
                        die ("such email already exist");
                    }
                }
                fwrite($f, $this->string);
            }
            else {
                fwrite($f, $this->string);
            }

            fclose($f);
        }
        if(!file_exists($this->file)) {
            $f = fopen($this->file, "a+") or die ("Error");

            fwrite($f, $this->string);

            fclose($f);
        }
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) { /*load the child class*/
    include $class . '.php';
});

$addTxt = new AddTxt();
$addTxt->addLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an class file, there should only be the class inside and no code. So in your case you have basically there files:

Validator.php

```
class Validator { ... }
```

AddTxt.php

```
class AddTxt extends Validator { ... }
```

index.php

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) { /*load the child class*/
    include $class . '.php';
});

$addTxt = new AddTxt();
$addTxt->addLine();
```